# Mobile Network not available despite full coverage

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, networking

I've been to my network provider and the problem is with my phone.  I woke up on Tuesday with an unread message but have been unable to respond since.  My lock screen says that I can make "Emergency calls only", but shows full network coverage.

I have CM7 on the phone, and tried a new install last night to no avail.  I did spill some water on the phone about two weeks ago, but the phone has been working fine since.  Most confusing is I received the text above at 08.00 and the problem has been present since at least 10.00 on the same day.

Any advice is welcome. Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: if you spilled water on it, that may be the cause of the issue. You rebooted the phone and you still have the same problem? Try a different sim (if its GSM network), and try your sim in a different phone.

Comment: Well it worked for over a week after the water damage so not sure why it suddenly stopped.  It's definitely not a sim issue, I was in the store today and go a brand new sim that worked on the clerks phone

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the standard ROM, if this also doesn't work you can be sure that this is a hardware problem with the phone.

I think the problem occurred when you spilled water on your mobile phone. It will oxidize and become damaged over time. If you had lost your phone in salt water, it would be destroyed immediately. When you lose your phone in water or spill water on it, you should take out your battery immediately and deliver it to professionals to clean it before it oxidizes.

Since the phone has been in contact with water, your guarantee is void.

**How a water sensors looks like:** http://altinett.no/2/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/futkskade-mb.jpg
There is two water sensors in this picture. One looks like a black circle and white in the middle, this censor has not been in contact with water. The other censor to the left looks like a black circle with red in the middle, this has been in direct contact with water.

**How an oxidized motherboard looks like:** http://altinett.no/2/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/fukt-korrosjon-lcd2.jpg
This case is irreversible.